# resize google cloud image

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, ruby-on-rails-5

We are looping through the list images url, which is actually, google cloud image url.
Can anybody suggest,

> how to resize the google cloud image url by adding some parameters to
>   the image url

so that we could improve the performance.

As a front end, we are using

> ReactJs

and backend is

> Ruby on rails

.

Comment: What have you tried yourself? Where is your starting point in code?

Comment: Actually, this is the url 
https://storage.googleapis.com/<project name>/33/57/fish%20manCroppedNO%20RINGS-3.jpg?auto=format,compress

I can access the image in actual size, but i want to acess the same image in smaller size.